# Button Click Event not Executing on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is very strange! The below code runs correctly when F5'ed in VS2010 but when I run it on the IIS7 server the button click event doesn't fire! I can't for the life of me figure this out! Here's the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Put your JavaScript code here.
    </script>
    <div>
        Hi World!<br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="button1" Text="Click Here" runat="server" OnClick="button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" onclick="Button3_Click" Text="Button" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="results" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="350px" Width="500px"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the CodeFile:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using Telerik.Web.UI;

public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.results.Text += "In Page_Load ";
    }

    protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        this.results.Text += "Hello! ";

        return;
    }
    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.button1_Click(sender, e);
        return;
    }
}
```

Page_Load() does run, but not button1_Click(). Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also need to remove the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` setting from your `web.config` if you have it (or set it to false).

Comment: Thank you!!! OMG, that worked. I removed the modules section which Telerik automatically added which included RadUploadModule and RadCompression -- we just decided on Telerik so I'm not sure what needs to be done for these, but again, thank you very much.